# Prolog, finding smallest number without if statements

Tags: prolog

I am currently using tkEclipse for my prolog and am currently stuck at this question.

Given base cases of an item with their name and number, I need to be able to find the smallest number without using rules such as if statements. 
eg. `anime(gundam, 1978)`, `anime(steins_gate, 2011)`, `anime(prison_school, 2015)`. and the answer would say `gundam` is the smallest number. This must not be hard coded because if you were to change the knowledge base then it should also change answer. Also, it should work if there are only two animes in the knowledge base.

I was thinking of something like this to start:

`anime(X, Y)`, `anime(A,B)`, `Y < B`, but things after that get tricky because not allowed to use :-

Comment: maybe `?- anime(X,Y), \+(anime(U,V), V>Y)).`

Comment: hi, I think this is the correct solution. but I am having a hard time understanding use of \+? can "not" replace \+ ?
anime(X, Y), not(anime(U, V), V>Y))

Comment: yes, (\+)/1 is the modern name of not/1

Answer (score 0):

```
findall(N, anime(A, N), S),
setof(X, member(X,S), [Min|_]).
```

Or, in one line:

```
setof(N, A^anime(A, N), [Min|_]).
```

Comment: why not directly `?- setof(X, P^anime(P,X), [Min|_]).` ?

Comment: @CapelliC - I chose the two-line answer as it is very easily understood, whereas "P^" is less so.

Comment: It doesn't make sense not to do it as @CapelliC is suggesting.